# Minoring in Digital Design

Tags: designers, education, digital

I am a computer science student that is currently working on getting my CS degree while minoring in mathematics. However, there are enough free elective credits left in my degree path that I could double minor in digital design. I hold a job in web development, but am going to be trying for a job in the game design and development field. Would having the digital design under my belt be beneficial  in any form, or is digital design not useful for the application I am think of? I would most likely fill the role of a developer or a designer, and not an artist. I don't know much if anything at all about this field (I've never done graphic design before), so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any kind of training related to anything design related and especially digital design is going to be beneficial in the immediate future. Even with a coding job, you'll have an edge with some basic understanding of design. That won't necessarily mean being an artist as in drawing stuff, but you know like making design decisions, structuring information in some kind of order, balancing stuff on a page and so on. Reading a Word file with zero formatting and visualizing what should go where and how to adapt that to your media.

I would take it.